# Tsql union in while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to union the same table together with itself while changing some value in the where clause. The problem i have is with the union between the loops. I can not use a table variable since the schema is too complicated to write by hand each time. Temp tables seem to be the way to go but I do not know how to get it to work and the correct syntax.

psuedo code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
DECLARE @var int, #tempTable
SET @var = someValue

WHILE expressionIncludingVar
  #tempTable = SELECT *
  FROM someTable
  WHERE column = @var
  UNION ALL #tempTable

  SET @var = someChangeToVar

RETRUN #tempTable
```

The result of the query should be #tempTable hence the weird "RETURN #tempTable".

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Another hardcoded example:
I am trying to unhardcode something like this:

```
 SELECT someAggregateColumns
 FROM table
 WHERE someDateColumn > @date and < someDateColumn < DATEADD(month, 2, @date)
 GROUP BY someColumn
 UNION ALL
 SELECT someAggregateColumns
 FROM table
 WHERE someDateColumn > DATEADD(month, 1, @date) and and < someDateColumn < DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, 3, @date))
 GROUP BY someColumn
 SELECT someAggregateColumns
 FROM table
 WHERE someDateColumn = DATEADD(month, 2, @date) DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, 4, @date))
 GROUP BY someColumn
 UNION ALL 
 ....etc
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, and I suspect there is a set based approach possible. Anyway, a temp table is for all intents and purposes just like any other table. Meaning, when you define it, you have to define the structure (ie columns), and fill it using `insert`

Comment: I'll edit in another example

Comment: Cant you just use one query with WHERE someDateColumn = @Date OR someDateColum = DATEADD(month, 1, @date) etc.? Alternatively use a TALLY table to CROSS APPLY to get your number of months to add on.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve, please give us some expected data output and declare @temp with column names

Comment: I don't understand why are you using a while loop cannot `WHERE column in (1,2,3,4)` achieve the same result? If instead of (1,2,3,4) you do have soem dates why not using BETWEEN?

Comment: I do not want to make the question too specific to my exact problem either. What I want to do is to union a table multiple times in a while loop without declaring a schema for the final table. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: No, your probelm is not using set/realtional logic and instead using a (wrong) procedural approach with WHILE LOOP

Comment: If you ask a generic question you will get generic answer. Give us a real small sample we can work.  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Right now your problem is you cant `UNION` a query in a loop. But you can  `INSERT` multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that I am getting answers that puts everythin into one select, which is not possible. Some sort of iterative approach is needed. Could you show how i could use insert then?

Comment: I should not say not possible, but the example is very simplified so. some other answer might seem obvious but it is not really what the question is about. It is about adding to a temporary table between loops in some looping procedure. If that is not possible that should be the answer and not some overly specific solution to just my problem. However I do appreciate everyone Who is trying to help. I should have worded my question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Recursive CTE works for you.

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(ID INT, ColumnA VARCHAR(10), ColumnB VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1,'A', '10'), 
(2,'B', '11'),
(3,'C', '12'),
(4,'D', '13'),
(5,'E', '14'),
(6,'F', '15'),
(7,'H', '16')

DECLARE @var INT = 4

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * FROM @MyTable WHERE ID = @var
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT T.* FROM CTE INNER JOIN @MyTable T ON CTE.ID - 1 = T.ID 
)
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM CTE

SELECT * FROM #tempTable

DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing what is different in each cycle is a counter, then why aren't you just write one query including all data?

Instead of `WHERE column = @var` use `WHERE column >= 0 AND column <= @maxVarValue`.

If your conditions are more complex, you should consider to have a small (temp) table which contains the columns to be filtered, then just join that table to your source to get the desired result.

According to the comments, you can use a tally table (or numbers table).

Example:

```
DECLARE @Tally (Number INT);
INSERT INTO @Tally (Number) VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

SELECT
  someAggregateColumns
FROM
  table AGG
  INNER JOIN @Tally T
    ON AGG.someDateColumn = DATEADD(month, T.Number, @date)
WHERE
  T.Number >= 0
  AND T.Number <= 3
;
```

The above query will return the results for the current and the next 3 months.

You can persist a numbers table and re-use it. I usually have one called `util.Number`.

Comment: Sorry, actual query is much more complex than the example and I would like to easily change thow many times i union. added andother example that might be better at explaining

Comment: @Jarnald Is the only thing what changes an incremental value in some expression?

Comment: yes, I added an example. the real query is still much more complex involving multiple tables and aggregations

Comment: @Jarnald There is an example for incremental values

Answer (score 0):

based in second example what you want is

```
 SELECT someAggregateColumns
 FROM table
 WHERE someDateColumn IN (
         @date,
         DATEADD(month, 1, @date),
         DATEADD(month, 2, @date),
         DATEADD(month, 3, @date)
        )
 GROUP BY someColumn
```

Now if you want a range is even easier:

```
 WHERE someDateColumn BETWEEN  @date
                          AND  DATEADD(month, 3, @date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a TALLY table and a CROSS APPLY you can generate the Dates to check:

```
DECLARE @Var INT = 4
DECLARE @Date Date = '2017-01-01'

;WITH Tally
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Object_Id) -1 AS Num
    FROM sys.columns
)
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY Tally
WHERE Num < @var AND
    MyDate = DATEADD(month, num, @date)
```