# tsql grouping with duplication based on variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create some aggregations from a table but I am not able to figure out a solution.

Example table:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(person INT, the_date date, the_value int)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1,'2017-01-01', 10),
(1,'2017-02-01', 5), 
(1,'2017-03-01', 5),
(1,'2017-04-01', 10),
(1,'2017-05-01', 2),
(2,'2017-04-01', 10),
(2,'2017-05-01', 10),
(2,'2017-05-01', 0),
(3,'2017-01-01', 2)
```

For each person existing at that time, I want to average the value for the last x (@months_back) months given some starting date (@start_date):

```
DECLARE @months_back int, @start_date date
set @months_back = 3 
set @start_date = '2017-05-01'

SELECT person, avg(the_value) as avg_the_value  
FROM @MyTable
where the_date <= @start_date and the_date >= dateadd(month, -@months_back, @start_date)
group by person
```

This works. I now want to do the same thing again but skip back some months (@month_skip) from the starting date. Then I want to union those two tables together. Then, I again want to skip back @month_skip months from this date and do the same thing. I want to continue doing this until I have skipped back to some specified date (@min_date).

```
DECLARE @months_back int, @month_skip int, @start_date date, @min_date date
set @months_back = 3 
set @month_skip = 2
set @start_date = '2017-05-01'
set @min_date = '2017-03-01'
```

Using the above variables and the table @MyTable the result should be:

```
person | avg_the_value
1      | 5
2      | 6
1      | 6
3      | 2
```

Only one skip is made here since @min_date is 2 months back but I would like to be able to do multiple skips based on what @min_date is.

This example table is simple but the real one has many more automatically created columns and therefore it is not feasible to use a table variable where I would have to declare the scheme of the resulting table.

I asked a related question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473987/tsql-union-in-while-loop) but did not manage to get any of the answers to work for this problem.

Comment: Why does person 1 have 2 results in your expected output? If you are using `GROUP BY person` then they would have 1 row. Could you explain?

Comment: @Larnu beacase I want to union multiple results of the query example. In the expected output, the first row for person 1 is the average for 2017-05-01 and 3 months back and the second is for 2017-03-01 and 3 months back

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Some versions have access to grouping and window/interval functions that might help in working this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is the following:

Starting with a date (e.g. 2017-05-01), look back `@months_back` months and define a range of dates. For example, if we go 3 months back, we're defining a range from 2017-02-01 through 2017-05-01.

After we define this range, we go back to our starting date and define a **new** starting date, going back `@month_skip` months. For example, with an initial starting date of 2017-05-01, we might skip back 2 months, giving us a new starting date of 2017-03-01.

We take this new starting date, and define a range of corresponding dates (as we did above). This produces the range 2016-12-01 through 2017-03-01.

We repeat this as needed through the minimum date specified, to produce a list of date ranges we want to do calculations for:

```
2017-03-01 through 2017-05-01
2016-12-01 through 2017-03-01
... etc ...
```

For each of these periods, look at a person and calculate the average of their value.

The query below should do what is described above: rather than taking a value and iterating back to calculate previous values, we use a numbers table to calculate offsets on an interval, which is used to determine the ending and starting dates for each interval/period. This query was built using SQL Server 2008 R2 and should be compatible with future versions.

```
/* Table, data, variable declarations */

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(person INT, the_date date, the_value int)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1,'2017-01-01', 10),
(1,'2017-02-01', 5), 
(1,'2017-03-01', 5),
(1,'2017-04-01', 10),
(1,'2017-05-01', 2),
(2,'2017-04-01', 10),
(2,'2017-05-01', 10),
(2,'2017-05-01', 0),
(3,'2017-01-01', 2)


DECLARE  @months_back int, @month_skip int, @start_date date, @min_date date
set @months_back = 3 
set @month_skip = 2
set @start_date = '2017-05-01'
set @min_date = '2017-01-01'


/*  Common table expression to build list of Integers */
/* reference http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/build-numbers-table-you-need if you want more info */

declare @end_int bigint = 50
;  WITH IntegersTableFill (ints) AS
  (
    SELECT
  CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS 'ints'
    UNION ALL

SELECT  (T.ints + 1) AS 'ints'
    FROM  IntegersTableFill T
    WHERE  ints <= (
      CASE
        WHEN  (@end_int <= 32767) THEN @end_int
        ELSE  32767
      END
        )
  )

 /* What we're going to do is define a series of periods. 
    These periods have a start date and an end date, and will simplify grouping 
    (in place of the calculate-and-union approach)
  */


 /* Now, we start defining the periods
    @months_Back_start defines the end of the range we need to calculate for.
    @month_skip defines the amount of time we have to jump back for each period

 */

/* Using the number table we defined above and the data in our variables, calculate start and end dates */

,periodEndDates as
  (

  select ints as Period 
  ,DATEADD(month, -(@months_back*ints), @start_date) as endOfPeriod
  from IntegersTableFill itf
  )

 ,periodStartDates as
  (

  select * 
  ,DATEADD(month, -(@month_skip), endOfPeriod) as startOfPeriod

  from periodEndDates
  )

,finalPeriodData as
(
    select (period) as period, startOfPeriod, endOfPeriod from periodStartDates

)

/* Link the entries in our original data to the periods they fall into */
/* NOTE: The join criteria originally specified allows values to fall into multiple periods.
    You may want to fix this? 
*/

,periodTableJoin as
(
select * from finalPeriodData fpd
inner join @MyTable mt 
    on mt.the_date >= fpd.startOfPeriod
    and mt.the_date <= fpd.endOfPeriod
    and mt.the_date >= @min_date
    and mt.the_date <= @start_date
)

/* Calculate averages, grouping by period and person */

,periodValueAggregate as
(
select person, avg(the_value) as avg_the_value from 
periodTableJoin
group by period, person
)

select * from periodValueAggregate
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I propose is set-based, not iterative.
(I am not following your problem exactly, but please follow along and we can iron out any discrepancies)
Essentially, you are looking to divide a calendar up in to periods of interest. The periods are all equal in width and are sequential.
For this, I propose you build a calendar table and mark the periods using division as illustrated in the code;

```
DECLARE  @CalStart          DATE    = '2017-01-01'
        ,@CalEnd            DATE    = '2018-01-01'
        ,@CalWindowSize     INT     = 2

;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @CalStart, @CalEnd)) N = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS INT) - 1
    FROM syscolumns
)
SELECT   CalWindow  = N  / @CalWindowSize
        ,CalDate    = DATEADD(MONTH, N, @CalStart)
FROM Numbers
```

Once you have correctly configured the variables, you should have a calendar that represents the windows of interest.

It is then a matter of affixing this calendar to your dataset and grouping by not only the `person` but the `CalWindow` too;

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(person INT, the_date date, the_value int)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1,'2017-01-01', 10),
(1,'2017-02-01', 5), 
(1,'2017-03-01', 5),
(1,'2017-04-01', 10),
(1,'2017-05-01', 2),
(2,'2017-04-01', 10),
(2,'2017-05-01', 10),
(2,'2017-05-01', 0),
(3,'2017-01-01', 2)

----------------------------------
--  Build Calendar
----------------------------------
DECLARE  @CalStart          DATE    = '2017-01-01'
        ,@CalEnd            DATE    = '2018-01-01'
        ,@CalWindowSize     INT     = 2

;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @CalStart, @CalEnd)) N = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS INT) - 1
    FROM syscolumns
)
,Calendar AS
(
    SELECT   CalWindow  = N  / @CalWindowSize
            ,CalDate    = DATEADD(MONTH, N, @CalStart)
    FROM Numbers
)
SELECT   TB.Person
        ,AVG(TB.the_value)
FROM @MyTable   TB
JOIN Calendar   CL  ON TB.the_date = CL.CalDate
GROUP BY CL.CalWindow, TB.person
```

Hope I have understood your problem.